# mongoDB call to find() behaves weird

Tags: mongodb

This is part 2 of another question I had on find(). Initially the code was not printing anything, then a few folks pointed out some code that moved me one step closer, but no cigar.

Code looks like this:

```
MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost/catalog', function(err, db) {
theDB = db;

db.open(function(err, db) {
    if (err) return console.log('error opening db, err = ', err);
    console.log("db opened!");
    db.collection('products', function(err, collection) {
        if (err) return console.log('error opening users collection, err = ', err);
        collection.find().limit(100).toArray(function(err, results) {
            if (err) return console.log('error initiating find on users, err = ', err);
            else    
                {
                    for(i = 0; i < 100; i++)
                         {
                             console.log(results[i]);
                         }
                    db.close();
                    console.log("CLOSED");
                }                         
            });
        });
    });
});
```

It prints fine, BUT:
- if I put a breakpoint on the console.log call the app is unresponsive, bkpt doesn't get hit
- if I try to do anything with results[i] (i.e. write them to ES) same issue, the app becomes unresponsive.

I see it taking more and more CPU/memory. Can someone shed some light?

tnx!

Comment: put a breakpoint? in IDE?

Comment: Yes. I'm using VSC. I can get breakpoints hit anywhere outside the collection.find() call, but not inside it.